# Rails retrieve associated object through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-models

I am looking for the correct syntax to solve the issue below. I have 3 models: User, Client, Account

```
class Account
belongs_to  :client
belongs_to :user
end

class User
has_many :clients
has_many :accounts, through: :clients
end

class Client
belongs_to :user
has_many :accounts
```

I want to create a controller to retrieve all the accounts of a User through the Client model. I tried the following (line 1):

```
client = current_user.clients
```

which retrieves all 'Clients' that belong to the 'User' (I checked in the console). However, I failed to find the correct syntax for the next line to retrieve all the 'Accounts' associated with those 'Clients'. I tried (line 2)

```
@accounts = client.accounts
```

but I get the error 'Undefined method "accounts"'. Could you please give me the correct syntax? Thanks.

Comment: You need to iterate through your array of client objects. does `client.first.accounts` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'client' is an array of many clients.

First, change client to clients to make that fact more explicit.

```
clients = current_user.clients
```

You cannot call the accounts method on an array, which is why your method is failing. Instead you need to iterate through the array, calling your method accounts on each client in turn.

This should work, or will be close.

```
@accounts = Array.new
clients.each do |client|
  @accounts += client.accounts
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have models like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
  has_many :accounts, through: :clients
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :accounts
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :client
  belongs_to :user
end
```

having created a single user, a single client owned by said user, and several accounts owned by the client I was able to get just the accounts by using

```
    User.first.clients.select('*').joins(:accounts).to_a
```

This may be easier to do making Client an actual "join model" but in some ways this loose coupling seems a little more manageable.

Comment: `User.first` isn't necessarily `current_user` . note that the variable  `client` is equal to `current_user.clients`

Comment: absolutely true, just doing that for convenience